# How to pass variable form aura component to screen flow

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, aura-framework

Question :

i implemented screen flow to update case object and here i tried to invoke flow from aura component

flow invoking as expected but i want pass case id from aura controller to screen flow

how can we pass variable from aura to flow ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `startFlow` takes two parameters:

- `flowName` - Required. The unique name of the flow.
- `inputVariables` - Optional. An array of object used to set the initial values for the flow’s input variables.

In your controller you should have something like this:

```
init : function (cmp) {
    var flow = cmp.find("myFlow");
    var inputVariables = [
    {
        name : 'CaseId',
        type : 'String',
        value : cmp.get("v.caseId")
    }
    ];
    flow.startFlow("myFlowName", inputVariables);
}
```

You could take a look at [flow component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:flow/documentation) documentation.